# What is wrong in these steps regarding to connecting metabase and ldap?

Tags: ldap, metabase

I am not able to create connection between metabase and LDAP.

I am trying to set it up similar with our Zeppelin configuration:

```
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = our_url<br>
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername = our_username<br>
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemPassword = our_password

ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = cn={0},ou=people,dc=xha,dc=app<br>
ldapRealm.memberAttributeValueTemplate = cn={0},ou=people,dc=xha,dc=app<br>
ldapRealm.authorizationEnabled = true<br>
ldapRealm.searchBase = dc=xha,dc=app<br>
ldapRealm.userSearchBase = ou=people,dc=xha,dc=app<br>
ldapRealm.groupSearchBase = ou=group,dc=xha,dc=app<br>
ldapRealm.userSearchAttributeName = uid<br>
ldapRealm.userSearchFilter = (&(objectclass=*)(uid={0}))<br>
ldapRealm.memberAttribute = memberUid
```

When I tried similar configuration:
URL, Username, Password, worked well.

I tried use `“ou=people,dc=xha,dc=app”` for `“USER SEARCH BASE”`, but it did not work and I get error in log:

> errors {:ldap-user-base "User search base does not exist or is
>   unreadable"}}

So it seems, that `“USER SEARCH BASE”` is in reality `“GROUP SEARCH BASE”`.
The only one value which working in `“USER SEARCH BASE”` is `“OU=group,DC=xha, DC=app”`

I tried for `“USER FILTER”:<br>`

```
cn={login},ou=people,dc=xha,dc=app<br>
(&(objectClass=)(uid={0}))<br>
(&(objectClass=)(uid={login}))<br>
(&(objectClass=)(memberUid={0}))<br>
(&(objectClass=)(memberUid={login}))<br>
{uid={login}}<br>
(&(objectclass=*)(cn={login}))<br>
```

I also tried with empty filter.

Nothing works yet and I am stuck on this for like 2 weeks.
In log is just:

> {:errors {:password “did not match stored password”}}

I also tried steps in https://discourse.metabase.com/t/ldap-debugging/2741 but I am still not able to make it work.

Our “LDAP” accounts have no email -> https://discourse.metabase.com/t/autenticate-by-ldap-a-user-that-have-no-email/5215 
I do not know if this is still “hardcoded” in version: 0.34.2

So, do you have any suggestions, how can I figured it out?

Thank you in advance
Peter

Comment: To confirm, are you using the same credentials for both systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out. "OU=people,DC=xha, DC=app" was correct, but our LDAP schema was huge and there were errors in LDAP's logs, that "SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED". So we started using MariaDB for storing Metabase settings and  I saved settings with "OU=group,DC=xha, DC=app" and then manually changed to OU=people,DC=xha, DC=appin MariaDB.